# ASUS HD 7770 graphics card. Power supply issues

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building

Here is the power supply socket on my graphics card:

[image: graphics card power supply socket]

And here is the corresponding connector on my PSU:

[image: power supply connection]

All seems well, but the manual seems to be saying that the supply connector needs to have its middle upper pin missing? (The 6 pin illustration)

[image: Asus manual]

Is this right? ASUS seems to have the same manual for all its cards, so can this detail be glossed over?

Comment: It's keyed if it fits in the hole it's good to go

Comment: That's reassuring to know. It's just if you try to connect a FireWire hub to a usb connection it'll damage components, despite the fact the pins align. Just want to be sure with this £150 graphics card!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that the card doesn't need that particular pin, it may be for an unsupported feature or future expansion.  I saw the same thing with one of my video cards, and didn't have an issue when I plugged in the same connector you have in your hand their.

Answer (score 0):

This is the manufacturer's generic explanation to the lowest common denominator of tech knowledgeable users (they may have very little experience) of what plug socket should be used on a particular plug of their cards. You have picked up on a detail that should have no problem in your case as there are available pins on your card to accept the socket from your PSU.

If you look at their 8 pin example, you can see that there are two types, and the holes are keyed differently, so they indicate by check and "X" what the correct plug should be from the power supply.